# bash: run command from script, but affect the shell where it´s called from

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

There is a script that should change the path of the shell where it was run from. I used this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TTY=$(tty)
echo -e "cd /tmp/ \r" > $TTY
exit
```

But that does not work. Is there a way to achieve this at all?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what exactly you want to achieve please? For example `eval "cd /tmp/"` will go to tmp dir.

Comment: This cannot be done. No process can change any part of the environment of its parent. It is possible for the parent to *source* such a command inline, but that may be a security issue because the sourced file may have been attacked.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I have a script that scans documents and creates PDFs from them and stores them in a specific directory. It would have been nice if that script could take me directly into that directory.

Comment: SOLVED I found the solution now with a hint I read somewhere else. I created a bash function that contains " cd $HOME/mystuff ; $HOME/bin/scan.sh" and this function actually takes me to the desired directory and executes my tool :-)